# How to apply mean/min/max merge functions on a vector layer to create a stars raster?

Tags: raster, gdal, r, sf, stars

### Problem

I would like to `stars::st_rasterize` a vector layers of an `sf` object using aggregation functions such as mean/median/max/min.

`raster::rasterize` lets me use `mean`, `min` etc. and even define arbitrary functions to do that.

Is there any elegant way to stay in the `sf/stars` universe to do that too, preferably using `stars::st_rasterize`?

### Example

```
library("sf")
library("stars")
library("raster")    

# Create sf object (type points)
data(meuse)
meuse_sf <-
  st_as_sf(meuse, coords = c("x", "y"), agr = "constant") %>%
  st_set_crs(28992)
head(meuse_sf)

# Create stars object for bbox of sf object
dxy = 500 # metres
meuse_stars <-
  st_as_stars(st_bbox(meuse_sf), dx = dxy, dy = dxy) # 500mx500m cells

# Plot stars object and overlay points
plot(
  meuse_stars,
  text_values = TRUE,
  breaks = "equal",
  reset = FALSE
)
plot(st_geometry(meuse_sf$geometry),
     add = TRUE,
     pch = 4,
     col = "red"
     )
```

[image]

Using the raster package, I can actually do what I want: calculate the mean(zinc) per cell:

```
meuse_raster <- as(meuse_stars, "Raster")
meuse_raster_zinc <-
  rasterize(meuse_sf, meuse_raster, "zinc", fun = mean)
plot(meuse_raster_zinc, main ="Mean zinc value per cell")
```

[image]

Using `stars::st_rasterize` works only for COUNTing observations (="MERGE_ALG=ADD")

```
meuse_sf$obs <- 1
meuse_stars_obs <- st_rasterize(meuse_sf["obs"], meuse_stars, options = "MERGE_ALG=ADD")
plot(meuse_stars_obs, main ="Number of obs per cell")
```

[image]

When I want to apply a different merge algorithm (such as MEAN), `stars::st_rasterize` throws an ERROR, obviously because GDAL doesn't provide MEAN.

```
st_rasterize(meuse_sf["zinc"], meuse_stars, options = "MERGE_ALG=MEAN")
# Warning message:
# In CPL_rasterize(file, driver, st_geometry(sf), values, options,  :
#  GDAL Error 1: Unrecognized value 'MEAN' for MERGE_ALG.
```

I refferred to the [`gdal_rasterize`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html) doc, but could not really figure out which other MERGE algorithms are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you can't do that as the gdal_alg option doesn't have that option. gdal just have REPLACE/ADD for MERGE_ALG. [You can check there the documentation](https://gdal.org/api/gdal_alg.html).

Anyway, you can do that really fast with terra in this one line and then go back to an stars object.

```
library(terra)
r <- terra::rasterize(meuse_sf["zinc"], as(meuse_stars, "Raster"), fun = mean)[[2]]
r_stars <- st_as_stars(r)
plot(r_stars)
```

[image]

Hope it helps.